# nexus proxy not working

Tags: gradle, proxy, nexus

I configured a nexus proxy repository to a nexus repository group. When I start a gradle build I expected that nexus initiate the download of the requested artifacts. In debug log I found sth. like

> org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository -
>   ResourceStoreRequest{requestPath='/com.mycompany/myartifact/,
>   requestContext=RequestContext{this=org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RequestContext@585fb59,
>   parent=null},
>   pathStack=[/repositories/nn01/com.mycompany/myartifact/],
>   processedRepositories=[nn01], appliedMappings={}} :: localOnly=true,
>   remoteOnly=false, asExpired=false, ProxyMode=ALLOW

There are no request at the proxy target. Remote Browsing in UI is working.
The repository is not blocked.

I have no idea, what I'm doing wrong. Why get my request a localOnly flag that prevents the server to download the artifact from remote repository?

Important note. I use gradle for my builds. I found [Resolving ivy dependencies on a proxied repository with gradle leads to missing resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910321/resolving-ivy-dependencies-on-a-proxied-repository-with-gradle-leads-to-missing). There is no answer for now.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. It was a dependency like `com.mycompany/myartifact:2.+` in my settings.gradle.
It is not possible to get a directory listing over a nexus proxy repository.
I replaced the wildcard with the right version and everything works.

Comment: These ivy based dependency ranges should be avoid since they lead to unstable builds anyway ;-)